# Sequelize many to many relation how to apply query to "children" and return all children rows

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, sequelize.js

I am having hard time to get my query to return all "children" from a query using Sequelize.

I have two models `Offer` and `Tag`. These models have many to many relationship through a join table `offer_tags` (model `OfferTags`) and it has columns `id`, `offer_id`, `tag_id`. I am **NOT** using sequelize to create the schema for me but only as an ORM tool so I have created the models of the tables and created the many to many relationship like:

```
Offer.belongsToMany(Tag, { through: OfferTags });
Tag.belongsToMany(Offer, { through: OfferTags });
```

I am trying to create a query to get offers where I filter the offers by getting the orders where they contain only specifid tags by doing an **IN** clause using tag id's. I am able to do this but however I want to return the offers and ALL their tags whenever any of the tag id's match the ids in the **IN** clause but the query returns only the tags that are matched in the IN clause and not all of them. Heres my current query:

```
return await Offer.findAll({
  include: [
    Customer,
    {
      model: Tag,
      where: {
        id: {
          [Op.in]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        }
      },
      through: {
        attributes: []
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

That Customer include is just another many to one relationship between offer and a customer if it matters. However this query only returns the tags where their tag id is **IN** `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and I am trying to get it to return the offer and **ALL** of its tags if any of the tags are included in the **IN** clause. Also I am using PostgreSQL database.

Here are the relevant parts of my models if there is anything wrong with them:

Offer:

```
export class Offer extends Model<InferAttributes<Offer>, InferCreationAttributes<Offer>> {
  declare id: CreationOptional<number>;
  declare customerId: ForeignKey<Customer['id']>;
  declare customer?: NonAttribute<Customer>;
  declare tags: NonAttribute<Tag[]>;
  declare setTags: HasManySetAssociationsMixin<Tag, number>;

  declare static associations: {
    tags: Association<Offer, Tag>;
  }
}
```

Tag:

```
export class Tag extends Model<InferAttributes<Tag>, InferAttributes<Tag>> {
  declare id: CreationOptional<number>;
  declare label: string;
}
```

OfferTags:

```
export class OfferTags extends Model<InferAttributes<OfferTags>, InferAttributes<OfferTags>> {
  declare id: CreationOptional<number>;
  declare offerId: ForeignKey<Offer['id']>;
  declare tagId: ForeignKey<Tag['id']>;
}
```

I also initialize all my models with the same options if those are any help minus the `modelName` ofcourse:

```
{
  sequelize,
  freezeTableName: true,
  modelName: 'offer_tags',
  underscored: true,
  timestamps: false
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try below the revised Sequelize query, I modified the approach to retrieve offers that have at least one of the specified tags, while also including all associated tags for these offers. Instead of applying the filter directly in the `include` clause for `Tag`, which restricts the returned tags to only those that match the specified IDs, I moved the filtering condition to the outer query level. This is done using the special Sequelize syntax `'$Tags.id$'` in the `where` clause, which filters the offers based on the presence of any of the specified tag IDs. The `include` clause for `Tag` is kept without a `where` condition.

```
return await Offer.findAll({
  include: [
    Customer,
    {
      model: Tag,
      through: {
        attributes: []
      }
    }
  ],
  where: {
    '$Tags.id$': {
      [Op.in]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }
  },
  subQuery: false
});
```

Comment: I tried this and got an error like:

`  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  parent: error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "Tags"
`

Could there be something wrong with my model declarations or something? I think that the many to many relationship through the join table is causing the headache here.. I see this approach working pretty clearly with one to many relationship without a join table. I updated the relevant parts of my models to the main question. Could you check them out?